# Replace a string with corresponding value from a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have a list of strings and some text strings as follows:

```
my_list = ['en','di','fi','ope']

test_strings = ['you cannot enter', 'the wound is open', 'the house is clean']
```

I would like to replace the last words in the test_strings with their corresponding strings from the list above, if they appear in the list. i have written a for loop to capture the pattern, but do not know how to proceed with the replacement (?).

```
for entry in [entry for entry in test_strings]:
    if entry.split(' ', 1)[-1].startswith(tuple(my_list)):
          output = entry.replace(entry,?)
```

as output I would like to have:

```
 output = ['you cannot en', 'the wound is ope', 'the house is clean']
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show a sample output for this input

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. i have added a sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i,v in enumerate(test_strings):
    last_term = v.split(' ')[-1]
    for k in my_list:
        if last_term.startswith(k):
            test_strings[i] = v.replace(last_term,k)
            break
print(test_strings)  

['you cannot en', 'the wound is ope', 'the house is clean']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
my_list = ['en', 'di', 'fi', 'ope']

test_strings = ['you cannot enter', 'the wound is open', 'the house is clean']

for i in range(len(test_strings)):
    temp = test_strings[i].split(" ")
    last_word = temp[-1]
    for j in my_list:
        if last_word.startswith(j):
            break
    else:
        j = last_word
    temp[-1] = j
    test_strings[i] = " ".join(temp)
```

After this, `test_strings` will be what is required.
For replacing the text, the `index` of the list has been reassigned to the new text.